# Create dictionary from txt file python

Tags: python

I have a txt file like this:

```
1234 John Smith
2345 Joe Bloggs
12 Matt Kemp
etc.
```

I also have a copy of the text file with each value like "value".
I want to create a dictionary in the form:

```
['1234': 'John Smith', '2345': 'Joe Bloggs', '12': 'Matt Kemp']
```

My current code is:

```
validclubs = {}
with open("validclubs.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        (id, club) = line.split()
        d[int(id)] = val

print (d)
```

but with both files I get `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the main stuff was covered in other answers, but I just wanted to point out that you use `val` to assign the value instead of `club` from the previous line. Also you should make sure to strip `"/n"` from each line using something like `.strip()`

Answer (score 3):

`line.split()` is splitting on the space between the first and last name of the player.

The full syntax is: `string.split(separator, maxsplit)`, where `maxsplit` specifies how many splits to do.

`(id, club) = line.split(maxsplit = 1)` should do the trick.  This is also will handle cases where you have one or more middle names as well.

(Unrelated, your dictionary name changes from `validclubs` to `d` in the loop.)

Comment: Thanks, this solved it although I had to change the line to `(id, club) = line.replace("\n","").split(maxsplit = 1)`, otherwise I had `\n` at the end of every 'club'

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you unpack from your `line.split ()` which will give you a list of three elements (and you unpack just two element) Unpack three elements then concatenate the name and the lastName

```
validclubs = {}
with open("validclubs.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        (id, name, lastName) = line.split()
        d[int(id)] = "{} {}".format(name, lastName)

print (d)
```

If there is more than one case (not always name and last name) :

```
    validclubs = {}
with open("validclubs.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        myList = line.split()
        d[int(myList[0])] = ''.join(myList[1:])

print (d)
```

@omg's answer (with maxsplit parameters) is maybe the better solution here...i also learn something here ;-)

Comment: Thanks that should work however some of the names we just have first name, some first and last name, some first middle and last name so how would you work around that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use dictionary comprehension with `split`, `replace` and `join` functions to create a dictionary from each line in the validclubs.txt file.

```
 with open("validclubs.txt") as f:
        d = {i.split(" ")[0]: " ".join(i.replace("\n", "").split(" ")[1:]) for i in f}
 print(d)
```

Output

```
{'1234': 'John Smith', '2345': 'Joe Bloggs', '12': 'Matt Kemp'}
```

Answer (score 1):

here is your code :)

```
d = {}
with open("test.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        (id, name, lastName) = line.split()
        d[id] = name + lastName

print (d)
```